# How to analyze font substitution in Catalina

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, catalina, font

I used to use a program called [FontRevelear](https://www.nomicro.com/Products/FontRevealer/index.html) to analyze the font substitution behavior. Basically, if you type some Unicode character from font "A", but the character isn't actually in font "A", the system will automatically substitute it with a character from font "B". Determining what font "B" actually is is not easy. The FontRevealer program showed this quite nicely. Here is a screenshot from their website to show what I mean

[image]

Is there a program or something built into the system that can do this for macOS Catalina?Unfortunately, FontRevealer isn't 64-bit and it appears to be abandonware.

Comment: FontBook will let you search for any unicode character and then it will list all the fonts where that character appears.  Does that do what you want?

Comment: @Allan that's not completely what I'm looking for, but it would help. But how do I do that? I don't see any option in Font Book for it. I guess you can do it in the "Emoji and Symbols" thing.

Comment: Enter your Unicode char in the search box in FontBook.  It will search and list the fonts it appears in.

Comment: @Allan I did that and it doesn't seem to search for fonts that contain the character. The search bar only seems to search for fonts whose name contains the given search term.